# Create Scriptable Object with constant, Unique ID

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use Scriptable Objects to create Items for my Unity Game. Let's say I create a Stick, a Sword and a Helmet. Now to use them, I need to drag them into a list and on game start, each item get's an ID assigned which is also the position in the list, as I simply loop through the list to assign ID's. Now I can access the item by using the index it has or, as shown in most of the tutorials about ScriptableObjects, we can then add the item and the id to a Dictionary to better access them.

Stick is 0, Sword is 1 and Helmet is 2. Now I decide to remove the sword with a patch so helmet gets the ID of 1. Now every savegame is broken as swords become helmets.

How can I handle assigning fixed ID's which wont change and wont be taken by another item until I really want to assign it again? I could of course hard-code the id for every ScriptableObject I create but as you can imagine, managing hard-coded IDs seems not like a good idea.

Comment: Is the ID being used to reference the type or the instance?

Comment: The ID is used to reference which ItemObject belongs to an item. The Item itself contains an ID which should then be used to fetch the item base-information from something like an ItemDatabase.

Comment: Why would hard-coding the ID's not be a good idea? Do you have thousands of items?

Comment: Actually yes, I have like 500+ Items at the moment

Answer (score 10):

Here is my take on it :

1. Create a custom attribute "ScriptableObjectIdAttribute", you can use it in front of whatever you need to be an id.
2. Make a custom property drawer in order to initialize the id the first time you access the object in the inspector and also to make it non-editable by the inspector.
3. (Optional) Make a base class with that Id property and extend all your ScriptableObjects which need a unique Id from it.

BaseScriptableObject.cs :

```
using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScriptableObjectIdAttribute : PropertyAttribute { }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(ScriptableObjectIdAttribute))]
public class ScriptableObjectIdDrawer : PropertyDrawer {
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {
        GUI.enabled = false;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property.stringValue)) {
            property.stringValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, label, true);
        GUI.enabled = true;
    }
}
#endif

public class BaseScriptableObject : ScriptableObject {
    [ScriptableObjectId]
    public string Id;
}
```

Weapon.cs :

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "weapon", menuName = "Items/Weapon")]
public class Weapon : BaseScriptableObject {
    public int Attack;
    public int Defence;
}
```

Result :
[image]

Comment: Your answer is truly amazing, i could not achieve by myself.

I modified my code to use the Unity's own guid system (from the .meta file):
`AssetDatabase.TryGetGUIDAndLocalFileIdentifier(property.serializedObject.targetObject, out guid, out local_id)`

Comment: Nice take, although this is only useful for scenarios where ScriptableObjects are created in the editor. It doesn't work for SOs instatiated at runtime, which might be important in some cases.
Also it falls apart when you duplicate an existing ScriptableObject. You would need check for duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

Create a string "ID" variable, check if it is empty when the Scriptable Objects Validates. If it is empty Create a GUID, if it is not, do nothing.

```
public string UID;
        private void OnValidate()
        {
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (UID == "")
            {
                UID = GUID.Generate().ToString();
                UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
            }
    #endif
        }
```

This is how i did it, it also sets the scriptable object to dirty so it does not reset when you restart the unity editor.

You can go a step further and make the UID field read only to prevent changing it by accident.

Comment: Amazing solution. But this poses a large problem if an item is duplicated. Meaning duplicate IDs will quickly stack up.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using for a simple, duplicate safe method.

```
public class YourObject : ScriptableObject
{
    public string UID;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UID))
        {
            AssignNewUID();
        }
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        AssignNewUID();
    }

    public void AssignNewUID()
    {
        UID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this a duplicate safe method? Reset() is not called when duplicating a scriptable object

Answer (score 0):

Building on BlueBossa's solution, I solved* the copy safety issue.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScriptableObjectIdAttribute : PropertyAttribute { }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(ScriptableObjectIdAttribute))]
public class ScriptableObjectIdDrawer : PropertyDrawer {
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {
        GUI.enabled = false;
        
        Object owner = property.serializedObject.targetObject;
        // This is the unity managed GUID of the scriptable object, which is always unique :3
        string unityManagedGuid = AssetDatabase.AssetPathToGUID(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(owner));
        
        if (property.stringValue != unityManagedGuid) {
            property.stringValue = unityManagedGuid;
        }
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, label, true);
        
        GUI.enabled = true;
    }
}
#endif

public class ScriptableObjectWithGUID : ScriptableObject {

    [ScriptableObjectId]
    public string id;
}
```

*Duplicating a ScriptableObjectWithGUID instance will still have the same id value until any change is made to it, so that's something to keep in mind. As long as you don't plan to duplicate SO's without actually changing anything, you should be fine - set and forget.

[image: Image of the id visible on a scriptable object]

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my improved version of sulition based on BlueBossa's answer. It includes equality members for SO (which I think is the main reason of having unique ID), Regenerate ID button in property drawer, and pre-build check for missing or duplicated ids.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Build;
#endif

public class ScriptableObjectIdAttribute : PropertyAttribute
{
}

public class ScriptableObjectWithId : ScriptableObject, IEquatable<ScriptableObjectWithId>
{
    [field: ScriptableObjectId] [field: SerializeField] public string Id { get; private set; }

    public bool Equals(ScriptableObjectWithId other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((ScriptableObjectWithId)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // ReSharper disable once NonReadonlyMemberInGetHashCode
        return HashCode.Combine(Id);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ScriptableObjectWithId left, ScriptableObjectWithId right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ScriptableObjectWithId left, ScriptableObjectWithId right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}

#if UNITY_EDITOR


public class SoChecker : BuildPlayerProcessor
{
    public override int callbackOrder => -1;

    public override void PrepareForBuild(BuildPlayerContext buildPlayerContext)
    {
        var ids = new HashSet<string>();

        var guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:" + typeof(ScriptableObjectWithId));
        foreach (var guid in guids)
        {
            var path = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guid);
            var so = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<ScriptableObjectWithId>(path);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(so.Id))
            {
                Debug.LogError("SO doesn't have ID", so);
                throw new Exception();
            }
            if (!ids.Add(so.Id))
            {
                Debug.LogError("SO has the same ID as some other SO", so);
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }
}

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(ScriptableObjectIdAttribute))]
public class ScriptableObjectIdDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property.stringValue))
        {
            property.stringValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        var propertyRect = new Rect(position);
        propertyRect.xMax -= 100;
        var buttonRect = new Rect(position);
        buttonRect.xMin = position.xMax - 100;

        GUI.enabled = false;
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(propertyRect, property, label, true);
        GUI.enabled = true;

        if (GUI.Button(buttonRect, "Regenerate ID"))
        {
            property.stringValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
    }
}
#endif
```